# Calculating the internal volume of a cube with wall thickness

Tags: geometry, volume

I am trying to find a formal for calculating the internal volume of a cube.

for instance:

```
[][][][][]
[]{}{}{}[]
[]{}{}{}[]
[]{}{}{}[]
[][][][][]
```

with a height of $5m$, while each `[]` and `{}` represents $1m^3$ block.

with this example the internal cube (`{}`) is $27m^3$ (3*3*3).

I'm sure that's not a very good explanation, let me try another way. Imagine a cube at 5*5*5. Each block is $1m^3$. There must be a floor, ceiling, and walls. Given this requirement, this leaves the 3*3*3 inner cube.

Another example is a 3*3*3 leaving an interior of 1*1*1.

The question then is what's a formula that could calculate the inner volume given `A` by `B` by `C`?

This may not be a cube either could be a rectangle.

Comment: What about (a-2)(b-2)(c-2)?

Comment: A block $A \times B \times C$ is a parallelepiped or brick, but not a cube unless $A=B=C$

Comment: @RossMillikan of course, I had given a cube as two examples and had realized the possibility of other shapes.

Comment: I appreciate the amount of effort you put into explaining your problem clearly. Not everyone does this. Thanks!

Comment: @MJD You're welcome. I spend a lot of time on SO so I try my best to write my own questions the way I expect others to write theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each dimension, the walls will subtract 1 from each side (top-bottom, left-right, etc) so the inner volume of $A\times B\times C$ is $(A-2) \times (B-2) \times (C-2)$

Comment: I thought of that but it seemed to simple. Given 6*7*4 the inner dimensions should be $40m^3$? Right? Guess this question was more of a sanity check :)

Comment: @Eonasdan:  That is correct.

Comment: well I feel dumb now. Will accept in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

This is the volume of a cube with a height of initial height-2.